# C++ nested inheritance error "expected class-name before ‘{’ token"

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-errors

So I get the following compile error when trying to compile my project:

```
g++ -Wall -c --std=c++11 source.cpp token.cpp
g++ -Wall -c --std=c++11 pascalToken.cpp
pascalWordToken.hpp:7:1: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
g++ -Wall -c --std=c++11 pascalWordToken.cpp
pascalWordToken.hpp:7:1: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token`
```

the following code has been truncated to keep the post as small as possible, I hope all the relevant parts are present.

token.hpp base class interface

```
#ifndef TOKEN_HPP
#define TOKEN_HPP

#include "source.hpp"

class Token {
public:
    Token(Source& source_ref);
    // public getter methods

protected:
    // protected member variables
    void extract();
    // more code ...
};

#endif // TOKEN_HPP
```

token.cpp base class source

```
#include "token.hpp"

Token::Token(Source& source_ref)
{
    // initialization of some member variables
    extract();
}

void Token::extract()
{
    // some code
}
```

pascalToken.hpp file

```
#ifndef PASCAL_TOKEN_HPP
#define PASCAL_TOKEN_HPP

#include "token.hpp"
#include "source.hpp"

class PascalToken : public Token
{
protected:
    PascalToken(Source& source_ref);
};

#endif // PASCAL_TOKEN_HPP
```

pascalToken.cpp file

```
#include "pascalToken.hpp"

PascalToken::PascalToken(Source& source_ref) : Token(source_ref) {}
```

pascalWordToken.hpp file

```
#ifndef PASCAL_WORD_TOKEN_HPP
#define PASCAL_WORD_TOKEN_HPP

#include "token.hpp"
#include "pascalToken.hpp"
#include "source.hpp"

class PascalWordToken : public PascalToken
{
public:
    PascalWordToken(Source& source_ref);

protected:
    void extract();
};

#endif // PASCAL_WORD_TOKEN_HPP`
```

pascalWordToken.cpp file

```
#include "pascalWordToken.hpp"
PascalWordToken::PascalWordToken(Source& source_ref) : PascalToken(source_ref)
{}

void PascalWordToken::extract()
{
    // code ...
}
```

Edit:

source.hpp file

```
#ifndef SOURCE_HPP
#define SOURCE_HPP

#include <fstream>

#ifndef EOF
#define EOF '\0'    // end-of-file
#endif
#define EOL '\n'    // end-of-line

class Source {
public:
    Source(std::ifstream& reader_ref);

    // some code ....

private:
    std::ifstream& m_reader_ref;
    // some private member variables/methods

protected:
    // some protected member variables
};

#endif // SOURCE_HPP
```

source.cpp file

```
#include "source.hpp"

#include <execinfo.h>
#include <unistd.h>

Source::Source(std::ifstream& reader_ref) : m_reader_ref(reader_ref) {}
```

Note that the code has been heavily truncated and there's many more files in the project, but they all compile fine and the errors don't appear until i include the pascalWordToken interface....

Comment: That last line in the post is tautologically obvious.

Comment: Whats with all the back slashes?

Comment: @NathanOliver the backslashes are not in the actual code i added them cause when i used a pound sign in the code segment it showed up as a different font in the post preview and the backslashes didn't show in the preview... stackoverflow noob here...

Comment: Ah.  Okay.  That is because you were not using the correct markdown for the code blocks.  I'll edit them out.

Comment: When I edited the code for better formatting I didn't know what do to with the backslashes so I left them. If they are not in the actual code then you should edit your question to remove them. Also please show your `source.hpp` file as well.

Comment: okay i will edit the post right away thanks for the response everybody...

Comment: Make sure that `source.hpp` does not include `token.hpp`, `pascalWordToken.hpp` or `pascalToken.hpp`

Comment: @drescherjm none of them is, i added the source.hpp and source.cpp to the post too..

Comment: I'm a little surprised that you get the error when compiling `pascalToken.cpp`, since the "offending" file `pascalWordToken.hpp` should not be included there.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg good point that's because pascalWordToken.hpp is also included in other files that are compiled along side pascalToken.cpp,<br/>`    In file included from src/frontend/Pascal/tokens/../../Pascal/pascalScanner.hpp:9:0,
                 from src/frontend/Pascal/tokens/../../frontendFactory.hpp:6,
                 from src/frontend/Pascal/tokens/../pascalToken.hpp:10,
                 from src/frontend/Pascal/tokens/pascalWordToken.hpp:5,
                 from src/frontend/Pascal/tokens/pascalWordToken.cpp:1:`

Comment: don't worry about the file paths displayed above the includes in the actual code work correctly and i have removed them from the post for simplisity's sake...

Comment: Then it's likely you have a *circular dependency* somewhere in at least one of all the header files you have. That is the reason why I personally avoid to include header files in other header files, unless absolutely needed, and instead use *forward declarations* as much as possible.

Comment: Yes that sounds like a plausible explanation, i will look at my code and mark the post as solved if that's the case. thanks, very much for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your #include "pascalToken.hpp" did not work in pascalWordToken.hpp file. Try to replace it with class PascalToken; and include it in the cpp file.

Comment: i get the following error when i do that, `pascalWordToken.hpp:8:32: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class PascalToken'`